# Buttons on the app don't work in an app made by Smartface App Studio

Tags: smartface.io

I was viewing my app on a mobile testing site and when I click on the buttons on my app they don't do what they are meant to do which is to navigate a page in the app. This is the code I used for the button:
[image: Code of Button]

[image: Code of Button Continued]

[image: Code of Button]

Thanks

Comment: If the answer was accepted, please mark it to let others know that. Thank you! :)

Comment: btw thankyou for your time

Comment: You are welcome! But the question has been answered? If not, let me know. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The show method have some parameters to work. These parameters are:

 `show(motionEase, transitionEffect, transitionEffectType, fade, reset, duration);`
Obs: duration parameter is optional.

If you don't know what to put in these parameters, just type `SMF.UI.ParameterHere`. You can do this with motionEase, transitionEffect and transictionEffectType. Eg:

```js
show(SMF.UI.MotionEase.plain, SMF.UI.TransitionEffect.downToUp, SMF.UI.TransitionEffectType.cover, false, false, 350);
```

By the way, you can use Smartface's API to search before asking here, you'll have faster results. :)

API: http://docs.smartface.io/